# Community Social Sign on Error

Tags: community, social-sign-on

When trying to login through google social sign on i was getting the following error.

**We can’t log you in because of the following error.
NO_ACCESS: User was not authorized for the community**

Can someone help whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In a previous challenge it had me register someone using my email & I had used my gmail account. I just created a new Gmail account and used that Gmail address & it worked.

Comment: @user2854376 : In my opinion, the edit you are begging to have accepted should be its own answer and not an edit to this answer. Even though they both reference Gmail, yours sounds different.

Answer (score -1):

These 2 steps should resolve your problem. Check the link below.

[image]

[image]

Check this link - [Link](https://www.slideshare.net/yujiyasuno/social-login-with-salesforce-communities)

Comment: These steps are done already, and when trying to login through social sign on i am facing the above mentioned error